# ViewModel not storing values when Ajax.ActionLink calling controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-ajax

When I'm clicking ActionLink and setting ViewModel values in controller I can see changes when View being rendered. But same values comes as null into Controller when I'm clicking ActionLink second time.

How do I store the value, so it comes into controller ?

View:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "AjaxTest", "Controller", new AjaxOptions() 
 { 
    UpdateTargetId = "updatePanel", 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "A()" 
 })

<div id="updatePanel">
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_UpdatableContent.cshtml", this.Model)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxTest(MyViewModel model)
{
    model.A = "A"
    return PartialView("_UpdatableContent", model);
}
```

Partial view _UpdatableContent:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.A)

@if (Model.A == "A")
{ 
    //Draw
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pass a model object via a GET request.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **this.Model** to your ActionLink following:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "AjaxTest", "Controller", this.Model, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updatePanel" })
```

This method passes the model back into the request, which **should** allow the update to happen.

Probably my biggest gripe with ASP.NET MVC is the fact that the various "Helper" functions are overloaded to the nth-degree, and not always consistently in terms of the order the arguments appear...

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Added this.Model and Action not being hit anymore. Maybe I have to change Action method somehow?

Comment: Made Action: public ViewResult AjaxTest(MyViewModel model) - still not hitting. I can see that link generated, that contains query string parametes for each property in view model and I believe Action method should contain paramater for each of this ?

Comment: No, there's a step I must've missed out somewhere. I'll have a play and get back to you.

Comment: Added HttpMethod = "POST" into AjaxOptions and added attribute [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] for my Action method. Now seems to be working.

Comment: Not sure why, but not working anymore. Modified original message, can you take a quick look if you have a time pelase?

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same problem. Setting `HttpMethod = "Post"` in the `AjaxOptions` fixed it for me, thanks Sergejs.

My final, working code is as follows

```
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        LoadingElementId = "product-adding-" +@Model.Product.Id,
        LoadingElementDuration = 100,
        OnSuccess = "AddedToCart"
    };
}
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Add to cart",
        "AddToCart",
        "Cart",
        new { id = Model.Product.Id, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery },
        ajaxOptions,
        new { @class = "button" })
<img id="product-adding-@Model.Product.Id" src="~/Images/ajax_loader.gif" />
</div>
```